# GKE: cannot main class not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy a containerized Spring Boot application in GKE. The deployment is successful but the pod goes into CrashLoopBackOff. I find the error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xx.yy.api.Application

Application class is a valid SpringBoot Main class.

```
package com.xx.yy.api;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude  = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xx.yy.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>My API</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.xx.yy.api.Application</start-class>
        
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>

        <!-- Maven -->
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.4</org.projectlombok.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>

        <!-- Junit & Jacoco -->
        <jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>
        <jacoco-plugin.version>0.8.4</jacoco-plugin.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.3.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <mockito.version>3.2.4</mockito.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.5.1</junit.platform.version>

        <!-- Sonar -->
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.5.0.1254</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.projectName>my-api</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
            **/com/xx/yy/api/persistence/entity/**.*,
            **/com/xx/yy/api/dto/**.*
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>

        <!-- Encoding -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-testing</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>private.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <finalName>my-api</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Runs integration tests -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement> 
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true</compilerArg>
                        <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true</compilerArg>
                        <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        
            <!-- Jacoco : code coverage -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/com/xx/yy/api/persistence/entity/**.*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/com/xx/yy/api/dto/**.*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <!-- JPA Query DSL  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <url>https://artifactory.dt.xx.com/artifactory/nexus-dt-proxy/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

The docker file I am using:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as builder

ARG http_proxy
ARG HTTP_PROXY_HOST
ARG HTTP_PROXY_PORT
ARG MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML="settings_cicd.xml"
ARG TARGET="deploy"
ARG artifactory_username
ARG artifactory_apikey


WORKDIR /api/

COPY ./settings_cicd.xml /api/
COPY ./pom.xml /api/
COPY ./src /api/

RUN echo "MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML = $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML"

RUN sed 's/PLACEHOLDER_ARTIFACTORY_USER/'"${artifactory_username}"'/' ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML} > tmp.settings.xml &&\
    sed 's/PLACEHOLDER_ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY/'"${artifactory_apikey}"'/' tmp.settings.xml > ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML} &&\
    mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dtarget=${TARGET} -e -q -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML}


FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine


VOLUME /tmp

COPY --from=builder /api/target/my-api.jar /home/project/my-api.jar

ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy
ARG TAG_VERSION
ARG TAG_BUILD
ARG TAG_COMMIT 

RUN apk update && apk --no-cache add curl bash
RUN ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN addgroup -g 1000 user \
    && adduser -u 1000 -G user -s /bin/bash -D user

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/home/project/my-api.jar"]
```

Can't figure out what is going wrong. I have tested the Spring Boot jar separately it works. I am yet to test the container separately. Any leads will help.

Comment: Did you have tested the container?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not run the container because of helm setup. I started from the beginning referencing to another App with worked. It worked for me. I did not get to know what was the problem.